# ABPersonViewControllerDelegate shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook, abaddressbook

For some reason, my shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson function never gets called, in the simulator and the device. Could someone look at this and tell me what I'm missing? From all the examples I've found, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "SWO.h"

@interface CustomABPersonViewController : ABPersonViewController
<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, ABPersonViewControllerDelegate>
{
    SWO *theSWO;
}

- (id)initWithSWO:(SWO *)aSWO;

@end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
#import "CustomABPersonViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "SWO.h"

@implementation CustomABPersonViewController

- (id)initWithSWO:(SWO *)aSWO
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
      //Various init code
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personView shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)IdentifierForValue
{
    NSLog(@"In here!");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

And here is when I call in the view:

```
CustomABPersonViewController *view = [[CustomABPersonViewController alloc] initWithSWO:aSWO];
    view.personViewDelegate = self; 
    view.displayedPerson = aRecord;

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: How are you testing that it does not work?

Comment: You can see in my code that the shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson() is logging "In here!". It never shows up in the log when I try it, both in the simulator and the device. I've also tried settings the return to NO, but the default action still occurs, regardless of the property type.

Answer (score 0):

Many default actions do not work on the Simulator. You have to try them on an actual device.

Comment: I've been trying it on the simulator and device, to no avail.

Comment: Did you actually tap on something?